# Android Webrtc Video Only

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin, webrtc

I'm very new to Webrtc. I'm trying to have a video-only as the viewer. Master is sending video and audio. When running the app on a Samsung phone, I can see that there is a call (when I turn up/down the volume, I can see it as the call's volume). It is possible to have only the video running? Please let me know what code I could share. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue. Again, since this is my first time working with Webrtc, I'm using AWS Webrtc Android demo. When creating the sdp offer, make sure you have **OfferToReceiveAudio** to **false**:

```
 private fun createSdpOffer() {
        val sdpMediaConstraints = MediaConstraints()
        sdpMediaConstraints.mandatory.add(
            MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair(
                "OfferToReceiveVideo",
                "true"
            )
        )
        sdpMediaConstraints.mandatory.add(
            MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair(
                "OfferToReceiveAudio",
                "false"
            )
        )

    ...
  }
```